# Crystal Report not showing on a VB.net 2010 program using SQL Server 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I got a VB.net 2010 application that uses Crystal Reports and SQL Server 2008. When trying to execute the report, the form shows but the `.rpt` doesn't show. I've tried to run this on another PC, and it worked. So now I'm stuck on figuring the problem.

Details:

- .Net framework 4.0
- SAP Crystal Report version 13.0.2000.0
- SQL Server 2008

Code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Public Class Form1

Public DA As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Public Conn As SqlConnection
Public Function executeViaSQL(ByVal sqlquery As String) As DataSet
    DS = New DataSet
    DA = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, Conn)
    DA.Fill(DS, 0)
    Return DS
End Function

Private SQL As New sqlConn
Sub displayreport()
    Try
        Dim RS As New [report]
        DS = New DataSet
        DS = executeViaSQL([query])
        RS.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RS
    Catch ex as Exception
        msgbox(ex.Message)
    End
End Sub
End Class
```

It doesn't show any error

Comment: Try to figure out the different both pc.

Comment: One pc run on win10, other on win7. It worked on the win7. Both has the same SAP Crystal Reports runtime